# Blood covering ground in Unity 2D platformer

Tags: unity, 2d, platformer

I have just started my adventure with Unity so my question may seem silly to experienced users but anyway I'll give it a try. If you could just give me couple of keywords I could search for in order to solve my problem I would be very grateful.

As a sample project I wanted to create 2D pixel platformer, something like Contra. All went well up to the moment when I wanted to add some blood dripping from my enemies. I got stuck on generating the blood particles and simulating them painting over the ground. The effect I want to achieve looks like this: (live example: http://jsfiddle.net/0pg0LpL1/4/embedded/result/ , animated gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWKIz.jpg)

[image: Expected final effect]

I am wondering what is the best approach to achieve such effect. I thought about generating the texture of blood stains on the fly and placing it before camera. It would look like this: scene < blood texture < camera. The blood texture would be generated from lines drawn by "flying" blood particles masked by the ground/platforms texture:

- Blood particle traces:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRLGN.jpg
- Ground mask: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5nYX.jpg
- Masked traces (what I call blood
  texture): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvQnT.jpg

What is the best approach to achieve such effect? I know that generating texture with Texture2D.SetPixels on each frame is not optimal. I also see challenge in having a blood texture large enough to span over entire level to keep memory of all the blood spilled. Also the solution with one blood texture will not work if I wanted to have moving platforms that should also be painted.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: There is no "best approach" and such questions are ambiguous for this site considering each approach will have pros and cons that only you can decide on in the context of your game (like the requirement that there will be moving platforms and possibly extra blood drips? from your jsfiddle example). Personally, I'd pregenerate a sheet of various blood splatters and layer them/switch them out depending on how much blood hit a surface. Dynamically writing to and rendering textures is expensive but depending on your target environment you might be able to live with the cost.

Comment: @Coburn: Yes, you're right the question is ambiguous but that's the whole point: I don't know what techniques and best practices are available as I have no experience in game development whatsoever. I was hoping to get some direction like "have a look here, read about that, consider this" etc.  Btw, what do you think about having a grid of sprites that each would represent a pixel and its color+transparency would be modified instead of drawing a texture? Would that work faster?

Comment: Nah, sounds like it'd be worse than drawing pixels to a texture because now you have 1 sprite per pixel which in one frame of a 1920x1080 level might equate to > 2 million sprites not to mentioned problems with having to do any sort of rescaling of the game camera and more sprites and having to keep track of them when part of the level moves in and out of view.